# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/1533311989863.png ionic 3 (android)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I got error in ionic 3(android) at load image on  from local phone or sd-card storage,

```
path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/1533311989863.png"

<img [src]="path" > </img>
```

I also tried,

```
path="file://storage/emulated/0/Download/1533311989863.png"
```

OutPut:-

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/1533311989863.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read as base64 from filesystem using ionic-native File plugin:

```
File.readAsDataURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, fileUrl).then(imageBase64 => {
self.urlToShow = imageBase64;
});
```

Sanitize the base64 url:

```
    get imageURLSanitized() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.urlToShow);

}
```

in HTML use sanitized url as [src]

```
<img [src]=“imageURLSanitized”>
```