# @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.13 : Not allowed to load local resource : with webview 2.2.3 - Ionic CLI 4.3.1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-webview

After taking the photo from camera, these paths come.

```
file:///data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/files/1542782360167.jpg
```

I use Ionic 4 in which WebView is 2.2.3, all types of replies have been observed by applying but no effects came.

```
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "2.2.3"
```

I used to answer this one

[Not allowed to load local resource: ionic 3 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055126/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-ionic-3-android/52590478#52590478)

So I do not show the application on the device and this one is not the same.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: I also changed the image url to normalURL, but no one is working. Normal is something like this `/data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/files/1542782360167.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem.

I have done this link which is working perfectly.

https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/

And in my config.xml, extra did not write anything.

inshort : 
new webview plugin are not support `file:/// url`

first convert `url` into `http://localhost:<post>/url` 
using this function `this.webview.convertFileSrc(img);`

return this function value like this `http://localhost:8080/_file_/data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/files/1542782360167.jpg`

my suggestion use above link for same kind of problem...

Comment: This does not work for Ionic4 on iOS 13. Path returned is > ionic://localhost/_app_file_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/71F95B7D-4B08-4A74-A6AE-77946E9E5887/Library/NoCloud/d30fea00-83df-11e6-ac59-7fda303c65c4.html.

Answer (score 0):

Please try add this to your config.xml:

```
 <access allows-arbitrary-loads-for-media="true" allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content="true" allows-local-networking="true" origin="*"/>
 <allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
 <allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Comment: hi @markof 
Your suggestion was applied, but there was no effect.

Comment: What cordova plugin are you use for the camera ?

Comment: I'm using native plugins in; These are:

`"@ionic-native/camera": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
"@ionic-native/file": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.0.0-beta.21",`

and cordova plugin they are: 

`"cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "1.4.2",`